# Why is the result incorrect when assigning a string to const char * and then passing the const char * as a buffer (void*) to a function?

Tags: c++, string, parameter-passing

(I'm using the library [libmicrohttpd](https://www.gnu.org/software/libmicrohttpd/))

A const char * like this works just fine:

```
const char *page = "Hello World";
MHD_create_response_from_buffer(strlen(page), (void*)page, MHD_RESPMEM_PERSISTENT);
```

But assigning a string to the const char * will output a weird string on the client:

```
std::string str = "Hello World";
const char *page = str.c_str();
MHD_create_response_from_buffer(strlen(page), (void*)page, MHD_RESPMEM_PERSISTENT);
```

or:

```
std::string str = "Hello World";
MHD_create_response_from_buffer(strlen(page.c_str()), &page[0], MHD_RESPMEM_PERSISTENT);
```

The output of the second and third code snippets on the client are "ججججججججججج". Not "Hello World".

Why?

Comment: I'll guess that the string's lifetime ends before you use it, and that this will work correctly if you use `MHD_RESPMEM_MUST_COPY` instead of `MHD_RESPMEM_PERSISTENT`.

Comment: @Hasturkun Wow, didn't think about that, thanks!

Comment: I think it could help to mention the library that you use, and clarify if the observed results that you describe happen immediately when calling the function, or if these is something else that is done before the ouput is observed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`str`'s lifetime ends before it gets used by the library.

In this specific case, making libmicrohttpd copy the buffer should fix the problem.

More specifically, [`MHD_create_response_from_buffer`](https://www.gnu.org/software/libmicrohttpd/manual/html_node/microhttpd_002dresponse-create.html)'s mode argument needs to be set to `MHD_RESPMEM_MUST_COPY`, as your source buffer (the string internals) has a shorter lifetime than the MHD_Response returned by the function.

Comment: This seems to be a valid explanation.  However, it only make sense in conjunction with your comment.  Could you please complete this answer accordingly ?  Also not 100% clear to me:  for those who don't know this library, does [`MHD_create_response_from_buffer()`](https://www.gnu.org/software/libmicrohttpd/manual/html_node/microhttpd_002dresponse-create.html) make use of the string only at a later point (i.e. stores the provided pointer in the response object for later use) ?

Comment: @Christophe: I've added specifics. I don't really know MHD (and didn't want to delve into it), but the API expects to either copy or take ownership of the supplied buffer (And these responses are used asynchronously).